# Why get error message when trying to get column name from Hibernate in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, names

I tried to get column names from Hibernate query in Java, I did some search online and found a solution, but when I tried the code, it gave me error messages :

```
  private void executeHQLQuery(String hql,String ActionCommand)
  {
    try
    {
      Session session=HibernateUtil.getSession();
      session.beginTransaction();
      Query q=session.createQuery(hql);

      AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer INSTANCE=new AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer();
      q.setResultTransformer(INSTANCE);
//    q.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
      List<Map<String,Object>> aliasToValueMapList=q.list();

      for (Map<String,Object> map : aliasToValueMapList)
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : map.entrySet()) System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" - "+entry.getValue());

      List resultList=q.list();

      displayResult(resultList,ActionCommand);
      session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (HibernateException he) { he.printStackTrace(); }
  }
```

The error message points to the line : `for (Map<String,Object> map : aliasToValueMapList)`

It says : "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: sakila.entity.Actor cannot be cast to java.util.Map", why ? How to fix it ?

In my case how to loop through aliasToValueMapList as a list of EntityBeans and get the values of each item ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your Query returns a list of EntityBeans, and transformation cannot be applied to them. Maybe [this](http://relation.to/2133.lace) article will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using  `query.setResultTransforer()` will set the shape of result.

You are assigning the Result should be of type `AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer` and casting to `Map`.

So it is throwing `ClassCastException`.

It returns the results of type `AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer`.

Hope this helps :)

Reference : [Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setResultTransformer%28org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer%29)